# ubuntu/xrandr - Mouse Visual Location Not Matching Actual Location

Tags: mouse, multi-monitor, xrandr

I am trying to configure a multi-monitor setup using xrandr. I have two monitors, HDMI-1 (on the left) and DP-3 (on the right). By default, xrandr thinks that these are swapped, so I have tried to fix it using these commands:

```
xrandr --output DP-3 --primary
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --auto --left-of DP-3
```

This swaps the positions of my monitors just fine, but breaks my mouse.

When I move my mouse between monitors, it moves between them just fine, but when I try to click on something, my mouse click will register at the right position, just on the *opposite* monitor. This behavior is the same for both of my monitors.

What is causing this behavior, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Update: I have fixed the issue by removing the xf86-video-nouveau driver and replacing it with the proprietary Nvidia driver. I could then configure my screens using `nvidia-config`.